# Pandas: vectorised way to forward fill a series using a gradient?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Consider a dataframe which has a series `price` with gaps containing NaN:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"price": [1, 2, 3, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 9, 10]}, index=pd.date_range("2023-01-01", periods=10))
```

```
            price
2023-01-01    1.0
2023-01-02    2.0
2023-01-03    3.0
2023-01-04    NaN
2023-01-05    NaN
2023-01-06    NaN
2023-01-07    NaN
2023-01-08    NaN
2023-01-09    9.0
2023-01-10   10.0
```

My desired result is to fill this gap using the last known gradient prior to the gap, i.e.:

```
            price
2023-01-01    1.0
2023-01-02    2.0
2023-01-03    3.0
2023-01-04    4.0
2023-01-05    5.0
2023-01-06    6.0
2023-01-07    7.0
2023-01-08    8.0
2023-01-09    9.0
2023-01-10   10.0
```

This is easy to achieve using iteration:

```py
gradients = (df["price"] - df["price"].shift(1)).ffill()
price_values = df["price"].values
for index, val in enumerate(price_values):
    last_price = price_values[index - 1]
    gradient = gradients.iloc[index]
    if pd.isna(val) and not pd.isna(last_price) and not pd.isna(gradient):
        df["price"].iat[index] = last_price + gradient
```

```
            price
2023-01-01    1.0
2023-01-02    2.0
2023-01-03    3.0
2023-01-04    4.0
2023-01-05    5.0
2023-01-06    6.0
2023-01-07    7.0
2023-01-08    8.0
2023-01-09    9.0
2023-01-10   10.0
```

This works fine but is slow. This also feels like a common use case and I would be surprised if it was not built in to pandas, but I am unable to find it in documentation. Is there a better, vectorised way to do this?

Comment: What would you expect as result for the input sequence `[1.0, 25.0, 30.0, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 9.0, 10.0]` ?

Comment: `[1.0, 25.0, 30.0, 35.0, 40.0, 45.0, 50.0, 55.0, 9.0, 10.0]` - indeed I'm just taking the difference between the last two values prior to the NaN, not trying to interpolate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to use the last `diff` as a step size to increment the NaNs, you could compute the [`diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html), [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html) it, then use that to [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) the original Series, finally compute a [`groupby.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum.html):

```
m = df['price'].notna()

df['gradient_fill'] = (df['price'].fillna(df['price'].diff().ffill())
                       .groupby(m.cumsum()).cumsum()
                      )
```

Output:

*NB. I changed the input for clarity.*

```
            price  gradient_fill
2023-01-01    1.0            1.0
2023-01-02   20.0           20.0
2023-01-03   30.0           30.0
2023-01-04    NaN           40.0
2023-01-05    NaN           50.0
2023-01-06    NaN           60.0
2023-01-07    NaN           70.0
2023-01-08    NaN           80.0
2023-01-09    9.0            9.0
2023-01-10   10.0           10.0
```

Intermediates:

```
            price      m  diff  ffill  fillna  group  gradient_fill
2023-01-01    1.0   True   NaN    NaN     1.0      1            1.0
2023-01-02   20.0   True  19.0   19.0    20.0      2           20.0
2023-01-03   30.0   True  10.0   10.0    30.0      3           30.0
2023-01-04    NaN  False   NaN   10.0    10.0      3           40.0
2023-01-05    NaN  False   NaN   10.0    10.0      3           50.0
2023-01-06    NaN  False   NaN   10.0    10.0      3           60.0
2023-01-07    NaN  False   NaN   10.0    10.0      3           70.0
2023-01-08    NaN  False   NaN   10.0    10.0      3           80.0
2023-01-09    9.0   True   NaN   10.0     9.0      4            9.0
2023-01-10   10.0   True   1.0    1.0    10.0      5           10.0
```

You could also form groups of non-NA/NA and [`interpolate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.interpolate.html) with a spline for each one:

```
m = df['price'].notna()
group = (m & ~m.shift(fill_value=False)).cumsum()
df['spline'] = (df.groupby(group)['price']
                  .transform(lambda s: s.interpolate(method='spline', order=1))
                )
```

Output:

```
            price     spline
2023-01-01    1.0   1.000000
2023-01-02   20.0  20.000000
2023-01-03   30.0  30.000000
2023-01-04    NaN  42.828422
2023-01-05    NaN  54.949738
2023-01-06    NaN  67.071054
2023-01-07    NaN  79.192371
2023-01-08    NaN  91.313687
2023-01-09    9.0   9.000000
2023-01-10   10.0  10.000000
```

Graphical comparison of approaches:

[image: gradient interpolation]